# Partition output by key in Spark using Datasets API

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset, hdfs, partitioning

Suppose I have a `Dataset` of some case class, e.g.

```
case class Foo(colour: String, count: Int)

val ds: Dataset[Foo] = sqlContext.createDataset(Seq(
  Foo("red", 10), 
  Foo("red", 22),
  Foo("blue", 12)
))
```

How do I save this to a filesystem partitioned by one of the fields, say `foo` so the output directories would be:

```
/my-path/foo=red/
/my-path/foo=blue/
```

and the contents would be as follows

```sh
> cat /my-path/foo=red/*
10
22

> cat /my-path/foo=blue/*
12
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this using the field name of the case class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (Spark 1.4+)

```
ds.toDF().write.partitionBy("foo").text("/my-path")
```

From Spark 2.0 the `toDF()` will likely become redundant since APIs will be merged.

For other formats, just change `text` to `json` or `parquet`